# android reverse int array

Tags: java, android, json, reverse

I have successfully parsed JSONArray into list by using the below function

```
public List<Integer> ParseJson(String json, List<Integer> myList) {
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

    try {
        JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject(json);
        jsonArray = mainJson.getJSONArray("result");

        myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            myList.add(Integer.parseInt(jsonArray.get(i).toString()));

        }

        // System.out.println(myList);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Collections.reverse(myList);
    return myList;

}
```

Now I need the List into reverse order. What would be the optimized way to do that?

Comment: To be more precise, do you want to put the reversed json array into your int array?

Comment: `Collections.reverse(myList);`

Comment: for (int i = jsonArray.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)

Comment: @ Wildcopper yes you are right @Alexey Odintsov i also tryed it but nothink  changed

Comment: I would separate the array reversal from the "putting an array into JSON". They're orthogonal operations...

Comment: @Jon Skeet  how i can solve my problem?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "your int array" to start with, or why you've got a `myList` parameter at all given that you don't use the value you're being passed. Also, if your JSON already contains integers, you shouldn't have to convert them to a string and back again... why aren't you using `getInt`? Basically this question is too confusing to answer at the moment.

Comment: I have edited the question for peer reviewing?

Comment: @ dpsingh you are right.look i tryed Collections.reverse(myList); alsofor (int i = jsonArray.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)  but i did not solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you edited your question it seemed like you wanted to reverse the JSON array, append it to "myList" and return the result. If that's true, try this:

```
public List<Integer> ParseJson(String json, List<Integer> myList) {
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

    try {
        JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject(json);
        jsonArray = mainJson.getJSONArray("result");

        List<Integer> reverseListFromJson = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            reverseListFromJson.add(jsonArray.getInt(i));
        }
        Collections.reverse(reverseListFromJson);

        myList.addAll(reverseListFromJson);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return myList;
}
```

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/7amss9pu7/ i loged my jsonarray and result is this but still i can not reverse

Comment: Of course logging your JSON array shows the non-reversed list! But the return value is in the order you need, which should be the only important thing. Since you accepted my answer, I suppose you agree?

Answer (score 0):

`[1,2,3,5,23,534,23]`: Your JSONArray already contains ints, no need to convert.

```
JSONArray jsonarray = getTheJSONArrayFromSomewhere();
Log.d(TAG, jsonarray.toString(4)); // for debugging purposes. Check the contents of the jsonarray
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = jsonarray.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    list.add(jsonarray.getInt(i));
```

or this

```
JSONArray jsonarray = getTheJSONArrayFromSomewhere();
Log.d(TAG, jsonarray.toString(4)); // for debugging purposes. Check the contents of the jsonarray
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++)
    list.add(jsonarray.getInt(i));
Collections.reverse(list);
```

That does reverse your Integer List, assuming your JSONArray is filled correctly, and contains ints. Also, I omitted try/catch, you'll have to add those.

Comment: look sir i tryed your code i loged my jsonarray and  result is like this http://postimg.org/image/7amss9pu7/ but i still can not reverse this array

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:

```
ArrayList<Element> tempElements = new ArrayList<Element>(mElements);
Collections.reverse(tempElements);
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code to do this

```
ArrayList<Element> tempElements = new ArrayList<Element>(mElements);
Collections.reverse(tempElements);
```

hope it will work for you